# jquery datatables contains blank table headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, datatable

I am attempting to use the jquery [datatables](http://www.datatables.net) plugin to populate a html table via a JSON object returned from a PHP script.  I have a bit of confusion concerning naming of the json object and options in the datatables plugin.  Passing back a json object like so:

```
echo json_encode(array('data'=>$res));
```

yields:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

while changing data to `aaData` successfully populates the table, however without headers.

Several fourm posts mentioned the json object must be returned as aaData, but the datatables example documentation on their website gives an [example](http://www.datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html) json object named with data.

Here is my current client side code, I am relatively certain that my server side is correct.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('#result').dataTable({
        "ajax": {
            'url' : 'ppmAlarms.php',

        },

        "columns": [
            { "data": "location" },
            {"data" : "descAndType" },
            {"data" : "timestamp"}
        ]
    });

    });
```

JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
  "aaData": [
    {
      "location": "loc1",
      "descAndType": "desc1",
      "timestamp": "2014-08-20 11:34:10"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just realized I just have to specify my own column headers in thead, they aren't populated:

```
<thead>
      <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Position</th>
         <th>Office</th>
         <th>Extn.</th>
         <th>Start date</th>
         <th>Salary</th>
     </tr>
</thead>
```

Comment: I was scratching my head as well.

Comment: But how to add headers dynamically from data?